# JQuery event only runs once and isn't repeated

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a JQuery event that i would like to repeat for each time to the mouse is scrolled. Currently it will run once, add the css and then seemingly become completely inactive.

I'm just learning JQuery, i originally was using `.scroll` but that would not apply the css even once so am no using `.bind` with the mousewheel. I've tried a `.onclick` event but this does the same and i don't really know what else to try.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function() {
        $(".perspective-line p").css({
            transform: 'translate(0, -50px)',
        });
    });
});
```

my text is transformed once by 50px but then it is just stuck there and i want it to transform again when the mousewheel is scrolled.

edit* new script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var increasedValue = 0;
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function() {
        increasedValue += 50;
        $(".perspective-line p").css({
            transform: 'translate(0, -${increasedValue}px)',
        });
        console.log(increasedValue)
    });
});
```

Comment: `.bind` is deprecated for `.on`

Comment: Also look at debouncing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Events trigger as usual. You set fixed value to CSS
you could try something like that with dynamic settings:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var increasedValue = 20; 
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function() {
    increasedValue ++;
        $(".perspective-line p").css({
            transform: `translate(0, -${increasedValue}px)`,
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! this is the solution i needed. I totally misdiagnosed the problem here but will get to work implementing a dynamic change

Comment: Ive tried to implement  your suggestion of passing a dynamic setting and added my new code to the main post. However it isn't moving my text at all anymore. ```increasedValue``` is changing appropriately and printing every time to console

Comment: You may consider testing the direction and use .on instead of .bind: `$(window).on('mousewheel', function(e) {
        increasedValue += event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;`

Comment: @Harry Whitnear you missed `` commas for format string and should use it instead ' '

Comment: thanks again!. i have never used `` in my code before so didn't even notice it wasn't ' '. my bad.

Comment: Nothing much. `` allows to use format string in JS as in other languages, sometimes it becomes useful.

Answer (score 1):

Add `console.log('scroll');` in you function and you will see it fires every time you do scroll. The problem you have is that you have `transform: 'translate(0, -50px)'` and it is always the same value so eyes can't see it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is currently adding `transform: 'translate(0, -50px)',` css rule but what you probably want is to increase your `translate` by 50px on every mousewheel event.
You would probably need to save your current transform value and then on each mousewheel even increment this value and use that incremented value inside the css rule. You also might want to check if scroll was up or down and increment or decrement your saved value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentTranform = 0;
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function() {
        currentTranform -= 50;
        $(".perspective-line p").css({
            transform: 'translate(0, currentTransform + "px")',
        });
    });
});
```